# Failing fgets on a TCP socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, fgets

I'd like to replicate the following ruby code of a simple forking TCP echo server in C:

```
require 'socket'

port = 3333

server = TCPServer.new(port)
puts "Starting TCPServer @ port #{port} with PID=#{Process.pid}"

loop do
  client = server.accept
  pid = fork do 
    puts "PID = #{Process.pid}"
    while (line = client.gets)
      client.write(line)
    end
    client.close_write
    exit 0
  end
  if(pid > 0)
    Process.detach(pid)
  end
end
```

I started with http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/server.c and I changed the forking part to:

```
if (!fork())
  {             // this is the child process
    FILE *client = fdopen (new_fd, "r+");
    close (sockfd);     // child doesn't need the listener
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    while (fgets (buffer, BUFSIZ, client))
      {
    fputs (buffer, stdout);
      }
    fclose (client);
    exit (0);
  }
```

Basically, I'm wrapping the file descriptor of the socket in a FILE structure (`fdopen(...)`) in order to get `fgets(...)`. 
Is this the wrong thing to do to begin with?

This whole approach seems to work if I do `nc localhost 3333` (with the compiled server running) and simply type the input on the command line (lines get echoed back). However, if I do `cat a_multiline_file.txt|nc localhost 3333`, I only get the first 
line back because in that case, all except the first call to `fgets()` fail (I tried doing the same `fgets` in an infinite loop).

I'm curious to know what the cause of the problem is and how I can do line-by-line reading on a socket correctly.

**EDIT:**

On JoeManiaci's advice, I added:
`perror("Last failure");` after the while loop, which got me "Last failure: Illegal seek" for the second case.
So that makes sense -- seeking doesn't make sense on sockets, and if fgets does not only buffering but seeking too, that makes the fdopen approach out of the question for sockets.

Part 2 of my question remains--how do I do line-oriented reading on sockets correctly in C?

Comment: When fgets() fails, errno is set, so you should be able to print out the error and maybe get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Maybe the solution proposed in [this similar discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255663/illegal-seek-error-when-working-with-socket-streams-with-non-empty-read-buffer) on stackoverflow works for you?

Comment: Yes it does, user2719058! Thanks a lot!